# Getting blank animated time series plot with gganimate transition_reveal in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to create **timeseries animated plot** using `transition_reveal` from `gganimate` but getting a blank plot.

It works without animation.

I have referred some SO post & other links but still no success.
[Animated graph using gganimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518385/animated-graph-using-gganimate)
http://shanghai.hosting.nyu.edu/data/r/case-2-1-animation.html

**df**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
library(gganimate)

file_url1 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_vaccination.csv"

df_vaccination <- read.csv(url(file_url1))

df_vaccination <- df_vaccination %>%
  mutate(Updated.On = as.Date(Updated.On))
```

**plot**

```
vaccination_anime1 <- df_vaccination %>% 
  select(Updated.On, State, Total.Doses.Administered) %>% 
  mutate(State = as.factor(State)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Total.Doses.Administered),
         State %in% c("Delhi","Maharashtra","Karnataka")) %>% 
  arrange(Updated.On) %>% 
  
  
  #selecting dates divided by 5
  filter(as.numeric(Updated.On) %% 5 == 0) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Updated.On, y = Total.Doses.Administered,
             group = State, col = State)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(scale = 1e-6, unit = "M"))
```

**Animating plot**

```
vaccination_anime1 +
  
  gganimate::transition_reveal(Updated.On) +
  
  labs(title = "{frame_time}: Vaccination of Indian States",
       caption = "created by ViSa")
```

also tried: `gganimate::transition_reveal(along = Updated.On) +` but getting same blank plot.

Comment: Your code works fine when I switch to `frame_along` in `labs()` instead of `frame_time`.

Comment: Thanks @stefan, yes it worked well with `frame_along`. If you could post this as an answer then I will accept it & close this post.